# Регулярное выражение двухзначного числа

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Пишу код, который принимает с клавиатуры на вход массив чисел, запрашивать размер скидки, номер позиции и количество позиций. Дальше сделал регулярное выражение на проверку введенных символов, что это число. `"[0-9]+[0-9]*"`. Число может быть равно 0, но не может быть равно 01, 02 или подобное. Моя регулярка работает неправильно, так как принимает 02, например.
Оно должно пропускать числа от 1 до бесконечности и если число равно 0

Comment: Числа `01` и `02` совершенно корректные :) Если вы воспользуетесь строкой `Integer.parseInt("01")`, то заметите, что нули в начале будут отброшены и получится результат 1. Число 01 — это число 1. Почему вы считаете его некорректным?

Comment: об Integer.parseInt("01") я даже не подумал,благодарю за совет)

Answer (score 0):

Если *действительно* нужна регулярка для проверки чисел без нулей слева, следует проверить строку на единственный 0 ИЛИ на `[1-9]`, после которых идут 0 или больше цифр:

```java
private static boolean numberWithoutLeadingZeros(String num) {
    return num != null && num.matches("0|[1-9]\\d*");
}
```

> *Оно должно пропускать числа от 1 до бесконечности и если число равно 0*

Требование насчёт *бесконечности* строго говоря невыполнимо, так как исходная строка (класс `String`) или *теоретически* бесконечное число типа `BigInteger` используют массивы, размер которых ограничен, не говоря уже о примитивных целочисленных типах `int` / `long`, занимающих 4 / 8 байт соответственно.